# Ionic 2: cannot change date format after user sets it on date input

Tags: angular, ionic2, format, datetimepicker

I have this piece of html where there are two elements, a button and a date input.

```
<ion-datetime id="datetime-12-0" pickerFormat="DD/MMM/YY" min="2017" max="2020" [(ngModel)]="date.date"></ion-datetime>
    <button (click)="triggerClick('date1Input')" ion-button="" item-end="" outline="" class="disable-hover item-button button button-ios button-outline button-outline-ios">
      <span class="button-inner">{{date.date}}</span>
      <div class="button-effect"></div>
    </button>
```

I set the button to trigger the click on the date input and also set the model date.date to be printed on the button.

Inside the component I declared the object with now date inside:

```
now = moment().format('DD/MM/YY');
date = {'date':this.now};
```

The problem is: when the app starts, it shows the date correctly formated (DD/MM/YY) but when the user sets the date on the input, it changes its format to YYYY-MM-DD.

I've already tried displayFormat, ngModelChange (after the model changed it´s value, tried to format it) but had no lucky.

Is there anything else I could try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the date pipe in the view, which means that you would not format the date to `moment().format('DD/MM/YY');` initially. If you want to format it, I suggest you do it afterwards. So the following should work:

TS:

```
now = moment();
date = {'date':this.now};
```

Template:

```
<ion-datetime id="datetime-12-0" 
              pickerFormat="DD/MMM/YY" 
              min="2017" 
              max="2020" 
              [(ngModel)]="date.date">
</ion-datetime>

<button (click)="triggerClick('date1Input')">
  <span class="button-inner">{{date.date | date: 'dd/MM/yy'}}</span>
</button>
```

Comment: do you know how I can start pickerdate from today´s date? Because even inserting date.date as model and starting it as "moment()" the picker date starts from 20th january,2020 and not from today.

Comment: Seems like you need to use `toISOString()` https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/datetime-default-to-todays-date/53178/2 That seems to work fine when I tried it :) `moment().toISOString()`